# How to show my child widget on top of all other child widgets and the parent window of my app?

Tags: python, qt, desktop, qwidget, pyside2

I searched this everywhere, but couldn't find a solution that works. Basically I want to be able to have my child widget to show on top of the parent window, which already works by default. But there are other child widgets in this app.

I want my child widget to be on top of all of these widgets. I can't use WindowStaysOnTopHint because that makes my widget on top of every window outside the scope of the parent window.

I want to be limited by the parent window, where other applications can still be on top of my child widget, but within my app, I want my child widget to be the topmost.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is [`QWidget::raise()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise) what you're looking for?

Comment: Not really coz the moment I do that another child widget still goes on top even they receive focus.

Comment: maybe a modal QDialog?

Comment: I can't because I don't want to block the inputs to the main app. My widget is just for visibility like a thumbnail, so I don't want it to block anything, rather show things in the main UI on top of everything.